# Find literal string in with PHP and REGEX

Tags: php, regex

This is my first time using REGEX with preg_match and I'm not at all experienced with REGEX anyways. So I'm trying to find the string (case insensitive) `def` possibly followed by a string in an input. The regex I'm using is: `(?-i)def?\.`

I get the following error: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'd' in /var/www/process.php on line 11`

When inputting: `asdsa saj dasjdkj def ddas`

and the same error with any other input.

So what am I messing up with here? Is there some simple fix?

Sorry if this seems to silly but I'm a baby chick in this area of PHP.

Comment: Why are you using a regex to search for a literal substring? `strstr()` seems like a better approach.

Comment: @johnysweb hmm... seems reasonable. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [delimiting character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for your regex. This is the first character in your regex and must be a non-alphanumeric (non-whitespace, non-backslash) character. So the regex parser takes `(` as the delimiting character (bracket-style) in your example and thinks the d is a modifier after the closing bracket, which it does not recognize since it does not exist.

A better regex would be:

```
/def/i
```

which would match a "def" in the string. What are you trying to match with the `(?-i)` part? Has `def` to be followed by a `.`? Is the `f` optional? This is what you are currently telling the regex engine with your example regex.

EDIT:
Matching "Was" or "Will" at the beginning followed by a space:

```
/^(Was|Will) /i
```

Comment: well I saw this on the regex site so I think i messed up by putting different regex rules together

Comment: If you expand on what exactly you are trying to match I can update my regex suggestion. Right now I dont understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok, my actual task was to check if a string begins with the word "Was" or "Will" followed by a space and the string can be case insensitive...

Comment: The `^` in my updated regex stands for "beginning of string", and then there is "Was" or "Will" followed by a space.